# 3 column layout with fixed side column

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to  make 3 column layout, where left menu column and right menu column does not follow on page scroll and only center column scroll. I have done with it but on screen change center div mixed with others.

```
 <section id="wrapper">
  <div id="main">
    <aside id="left">
        <article>
                left menu
        </article>
    </aside>

    <aside id="right">

        this is middle

    </aside>
    <aside id="exright">
    this is right

    </aside>
  </div>
</section>
```

And css is:

```
    #wrapper {
    width: 1300px;
    min-height: 0px;
    /* [disabled]min-width: 1300px; */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#main {
    width: 1300px;
    min-width: 1300px;
    /*position:relative;*/
    /* [disabled]max-width: 1300px; */
}
#left {
    width: 280px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0.7%;
    margin-right: 0.7%;
    position:fixed;
    top:100px;
}
#right {
    width: 100%;
    max-width:700px;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    left:300px;
    right:300px;
    top:110px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
#exright {
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
    position:fixed;
    left:1000px;
    top:110px;
}
```

Comment: Show us what have you tried.

Comment: make your side columns fix-positioned and the center not.

Comment: u can use twitter bootstrap.
http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple css.

Just use

```
#centerdiv
{
    position: fixed;
}
```

And it should not scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
col{
   width: x%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qcebwq17/